# How do I get unlimited color options on LDD?

Tags: ldd

The title says it all.  I believe there is an unlimited option?  I just want to use it to make digital models.

Comment: never mind, I found it. :)

Comment: For the benefit of other users, can you create an answer post to your own question detailing how you enabled this option? Thanks and welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the unlimited option of LDD, when you start the program and the little window pops up that lets you load or start building a set, click  the tab at the top of the window that says **extended version** and click add new!  then, you'll have unlimited brick and color selection.